# How to check if selected text is a valid word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Question sounds easy as we think but I couldn't find a solution with any of this: regexp, asc, check space around

For example, in text "Hello world", I can allow "Hello" or "world", but I should not allow user-selection like "Hel", "Worl"

So, if user not selecting a full-word, then I should throw an error. Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a dictory with all english words.
then you cound check the text is valid or not.

The all words you could get from web api like below:

http://developer.dictionary.com/

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html

Comment: Thanks, but here I deal with multi-lang jobs and doing word check will pull heavy processing time :(

Comment: But there's not other way of checking the valididty of a word than comparing it to a dictionary. You should be able to redice search time by using indices/a binary search tree tough.